# How can i do a fill animation in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: animation, xamarin, fill, xamarin.forms

I need to fill up an polygon with Xamarin.Forms. Imagine a square and fill it with some color with animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest thing you can do is to use a `BoxView` view with `Opacity` set to zero and `Color` set to your desired color. Then do the animation with `yourBoxView.FadeTo` or `yourBoxView.TranslateTo` method.

If you need a border you have to make a custom render for a `ContentView` with border support and then put your `BoxView` inside it or you can use `FrameView` (rounded corners). http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/

This does something very similar: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=55r1wHdOLBo